# Adding Social Share buttons to Fancybox which uses the button helper

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

I'm currently trying to integrate social sharing buttons onto my fancybox image popups. There is a [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/G5TC3/) which Fancybox has created to demonstrate how this would be done...but I'm using the "helper" > `jquery.fancybox-buttons.js` ([see here](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/)). How do I combine both these custom solutions so that when the fancybox image pops up it has the social sharing buttons underneath (just like in the JSFiddle & has the button helpers?

Here's an example of my page's HTML for the Fancybox Gallery:

```
<div id="painting" class="content-pages">

<p>
    <a class="fancybox-buttons" href="painting/2011_b.jpg" data-fancybox-group="paintings" title="Sed vel sapien vel sem uno"><img src="painting/2011_s.jpg" alt="" /></a>

    <a class="fancybox-buttons" href="painting/beginnings-3_b.jpg" data-fancybox-group="paintings" title="Tegan Whitesel - Beginnings III"><img src="painting/beginnings-3_s.jpg" alt="" /></a>

    <a class="fancybox-buttons" href="painting/t-beginnings-i_b.jpg" data-fancybox-group="paintings" title="Tegan Whitesel - Beginnings I "><img src="painting/t-beginnings-i_s.jpg" alt="" /></a>

    <a class="fancybox-buttons" href="painting/t-beginnings-ii_b.jpg" data-fancybox-group="paintings" title="Tegan Whitesel - Beginnings II"><img src="painting/t-beginnings-ii_s.jpg" alt="" /></a>
</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First**, you need to load the js and css button's helper files (located on the helpers subdirectory of the download.)

**Second**, add the buttons helper option to the custom script. You may want to disable the default `close` and `arrows` buttons so you use the buttons helper only.

So the code you have to add should be :

```
// other options
helpers: {
    title: {
        type: 'inside'
    }, //<-- add a comma to separate the following option
    buttons: {} //<-- add this for buttons
},
closeBtn: false, // disable default close
arrows: false    // disable default arrows
```

See the same modified **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/kmLWf/)**.

Comment: First off, thank you very much for helping. I'm loading the JS & CSS for the button's helper files...and I'm including additional JS & CSS files for the social buttons (very similar to your JSFiddle example), but for some reason stil no luck. Could it have to do with the class names I'm using? I think they're a bit different than what the default fancybox files dictate. My class for each image is `fancybox-button` & I am also using `data-fancybox-group="paintings"` to separate the each gallery type...here's a link to the page I'm working on: http://www.teganwhitesel.com/#painting -

Comment: @Forb3s : I see the buttons, but I don't see the social media code inside the `title` as in the jsfiddle

Comment: Do you mean the JS & CSS files being loaded in the `<header>` tag? The file with the code from the JS fiddle is titled `fancybox/fancybox-social-buttons.js`

Comment: Well, the fancybox-social-buttons.js file has the social media code indeed, but that code has to be inside the `.ready()` method. Then you have the file fancybox-jquery-plugin.js with this code `$('.fancybox').fancybox();` that overrides the previous fancybox settings. Don't over-complicate things and set only those scripts you need.

Comment: ok... #1. so how do I place the social media code (which is held in the fancybox-social-buttons.js file) inside the `.ready()` method? #2 I've also removed any trace of the fancybox-jquery-plugin.js since it seemed like it was over-complicating things? Was that the right thing to do?